# How to generate dynamic Row in DataGridview by using TextBox and Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have one `TextBox` and one `Button`. I want to generate number of row according to number entered in `TextBox` by clicking the `Button` in vb.net.(`Button` and `TextBox` is outside from `DataGridView`)

Comment: what have you done until now? Can you show us the code?

Comment: Whilst `DataGridView` supports working without any data source, but in general it's better to use some `List`, `DataTable`, or some other data source for your DataGridView.

But if you want to use the DataGridView without any data source and want to set rows count directly, you can set `RowCount` property of the DataGridView.